# Is there a bug in default customer group for registered customers?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, magento-enterprise, customer

In my Magento website, guest checkout is disabled.
The customer should either register or login using existing account.

By default, the registered customers will be put under "General" customer group is a known fact.

But in our site, the registered customers are shown as "NOT LOGGED IN" customers.
Under Customers-> Manage Customers in the admin panel.

I know this is impossible by default, but it is happening.

Is there any known bug, which is causing this.

There are no custom modules which alter this behavior, in our site (Magento EE 1.12.0.0).

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default customer group id can be configured under

*System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options*

Check the value of the *Default Group* select field. Also check if you override that setting on a store view level.

**UPDATE:** If you deleted the configured customer group (e.g. *General*), and then created a new one with the same name, it would actually lead to the behavior you describe. Run the following SQL to check:

```
SELECT c.*, cg.customer_group_code AS `The Real Group Code`
    FROM core_config_data AS c
    LEFT JOIN customer_group AS cg ON c.value = cg.customer_group_id
    WHERE path = 'customer/create_account/default_group';
```

The query will also show any store level overrides. Maybe you can add the result to the original question.

Comment: Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group is disabled and moreover the  Default Group is set to  General.

Comment: Added more info in main answer.

Answer (score 2):

Review customer_group table, there is should be following groups with correct id:

```
0 - Not Logged In
1 - General
2 - Wholesale
3 - Retailer
```

Maybe during db importing/exporting id filed was generated incorrectly.